# Accessing RedirectAttributes in method without RedirectAttributes in signature

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Is it possible to access RedirectAttributes in method without RedirectAttributes in signature? For example, when overriding method like one below:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse res,
        final Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

    // add something to RedirectAttributes here
    // redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("attr", "value");

    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(req, res, auth);
}
```

I'm using spring 3.2.2.RELEASE.

Comment: What are you going to do with attributes?

Comment: @Ivan I need them to add indication that the customer has landed on the home page for the first time.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I was unclear with the question: what methods of the RedirectAttributes are you going to use? add/getFlashAttributes? I'm asking, because there is a way of accessing flash attributes directly, other parameters are available as request params.

Comment: @Ivan Yes, I need redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the DispatcherServlet class implementation, there are constants:

```
public static final String FLASH_MAP_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME = "flashMapManager";
public static final String OUTPUT_FLASH_MAP_ATTRIBUTE = DispatcherServlet.class.getName() + ".OUTPUT_FLASH_MAP";
public static final String FLASH_MAP_MANAGER_ATTRIBUTE = DispatcherServlet.class.getName() + ".FLASH_MAP_MANAGER";
```

Spring has a class called RequestContextUtils, which has methods:

```
public static Map<String, ?> getInputFlashMap(HttpServletRequest request)
public static FlashMap getOutputFlashMap(HttpServletRequest request)    
public static FlashMapManager getFlashMapManager(HttpServletRequest request)
```

The first two methods will give you an access to input and output flash maps respectively. 
The last method returns FlashMapManager, which has a number of convinient methods to work with flash attributes. See implementations of this interface for details, specifically AbstractFlashMapManager.

Comment: I have the same issue. I need to obtain FlashMapManager or outputFlashMap in my custom Spring AuthSuccessHandler and AuthFailureHandler. Manual says that FlashMapManager and FlashMap are never null (http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestContextUtils.html) but unfortunately it is. Could you please share your experience about accessing flash map manager or flashmap itself from the place redirectAttributes are not accessible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is "to add indication that the customer has landed on the home page for the first time," then HttpSession may do the trick:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
      throws IOException
{
    ...
    boolean firstLogin = <determine whether this is the first login>;
    <reset condition that caused firstLogin to be true>;
    ...
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        session.setAttribute("firstLogin", firstLogin);
    }
    else {
        log.debug("No session");
    }
}

// Controller for some page
@RequestMapping(value = <your page>, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showPage(<some other args>, HttpSession session)
{
    ...
    Object firstLogin = session.getAttribute("firstLogin");
    Assert.isInstanceOf(Boolean.class, firstLogin, "firstLogin");
    if ((Boolean)firstLogin) {
        <handle first login>;
    }
    ...
    return <page>;
}
```

This works for me. The logic behind this is that the login is in the context of the entire session that, presumably, comprises multiple requests.